# Changing the formatting of a datetime axis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, python-datetime

I have a series whose index is `datetime` that I wish to plot. I want to plot the values of the series on the y axis and the index of the series on the x axis. The `Series` looks as follows:

```
2014-01-01     7
2014-02-01     8
2014-03-01     9
2014-04-01     8
...
```

I generate a graph using `plt.plot(series.index, series.values)`. But the graph looks like:

[image: graph]

The problem is that I would like to have only year and month (yyyy-mm or 2016 March). However, the graph contains hours, minutes and seconds. How can I remove them so that I get my desired formatting?

Comment: [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), which can be used in `mdates.DateFormatter` as shown below.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# sample data
N = 30
drange = pd.date_range("2014-01", periods=N, freq="MS")
np.random.seed(365)  # for a reproducible example of values
values = {'values':np.random.randint(1,20,size=N)}
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=drange)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df.values)
ax.set_xticks(df.index)

# use formatters to specify major and minor ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: How do I turn that plot into a bar plot? `kind='bar'` doesn't work for `ax.plot()`.

Answer (score 18):

You can try something like this:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':np.random.randint(0,1000,36)},index=pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01',end='2016-12-31',freq='M'))
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(df.index,df.values)
monthyearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y %B')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthyearFmt)
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should check out this native function of matplotlib:

```
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

See examples on the source website [Custom tick formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date_index_formatter.html)