# How to increase xticks with a datetime index in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib to graph stock prices against a datetime index.

So I have a graph that looks like this:

[image: Data looks like this.]

And I need it to look like this:

[image: Data looks like this.]

I think it might have something to do with xticks, but I cannot figure out how to make xticks work with a datetime index. Thanks for the help.

```
tesla['Open'].plot(title='Open Price', label = 'Tesla', figsize = (16, 6))  
ford['Open'].plot(label = 'ford')  
gm['Open'].plot(label = 'GM')  
plt.legend()  
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Sorry my code is in the top image. I just added it below.

Comment: try reading matplotlib documentation: https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html

Comment: Look at this SO post to format x-axis using datetime. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43969357/6361531

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':np.random.randint(0,1000,36)},index=pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01',end='2016-12-31',freq='M'))
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(df.index,df.values)
monthyearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthyearFmt)
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Output:

[image]

#### EDIT:

Let's use `set_major_locator` with [`MonthLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':np.random.randint(0,1000,36)},index=pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01',end='2016-12-31',freq='M'))
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(df.index,df.values)
monthyearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthyearFmt)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator([1,7]))
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works for getting it into the correct format, but it does not allow me to specify the number of xticks there are on the x axis. My graph currently has 6 and I would like to have 9. Thank you for the additional information though.

Comment: @mikecaro2 is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. -1