# How to normalize pandas datetime index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetimeindex

I am having pandas dataframe with datetime index.
I am trying to normalize it to midnight.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html
What I get is the following

```
print('before')
print(df.head())
df.index=df.index.normalize()
print('after')
print(df.head())

before
                     cabin    hx
2000-01-01 00:20:51   21.1  19.1
2000-01-01 00:21:01   21.1  19.1
2000-01-01 00:21:11   21.1  19.2
2000-01-01 00:21:21   21.1  19.1
2000-01-01 00:21:31   21.1  17.9
after
            cabin    hx
2000-01-01   21.1  19.1
2000-01-01   21.1  19.1
2000-01-01   21.1  19.2
2000-01-01   21.1  19.1
2000-01-01   21.1  17.9
```

So hour, min and sec are dropped away.
Help appreciated.

Comment: This is just a display issue, if you look at the values they will all show times of `00:00` check `print(df.index[0])`

Comment: Thanks. print(df.index[0]) prints 2000-01-01 00:00:00. But when I pass the frame to plotly all indexes are without hour, min and sec.
If I do this:
for a in range(0,10):
        print(df.index[a])
I get this:
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: Is there a reason to display the time when they are all the same? It seems redundant, you can change the dateformat by specifying a format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968985/changing-the-formatting-of-a-datetime-axis-in-matplotlib/43969357

Comment: I think it is not redundant. If you look at original index, it is datetime with 10 sec step. Hour, sec min values are not the same.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question because normalize means to set the time to `00:00` so you need to now update your question and explain clearly what you really want or you misunderstand what `normalize` does

Comment: I have misunderstood normalize method. I thought it would shift the values starting from midnight. What it does is what I have got. All index values are midnight.