# Is mathplotlib.dates.DateFormatter() deprecated since strftime() is?

Tags: python, matplotlib

As a newbie in coding, I don't understand fully if I can use `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter()` without reservation, knowing that the function rely on `strftime()` which is deprecated.

I was trying to fix a tick issue (how to change date format for xlabel ticks) and ran into this [effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968985/changing-the-formatting-of-a-datetime-axis-in-matplotlib?answertab=active#tab-top)

This solution rely on `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter()`.
This is my code using this function:

```
import pandas as pd  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import matplotlib.dates as mdates  

fig, ax = plt.subplots()  
plt.plot(df.loc[:, "LAST_PRICE"])  
hourFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H')  
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hourFmt) 
plt.show()
```

This solution works fine.

The problem is that when trying to understand the function, I read that `strftime()` is [deprecated](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter.strftime)

Is it reasonable to use this function in my code, and if yes, why?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it reasonable to use this function in my code, and if yes, why?

Yes it is, because it allows to format dates nicely on a matplotlib axis.

> I read that strftime() is deprecated..

Indeed `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter.strftime` is deprectated. But you're not using it anyways. You are using `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter` and that is fully functional and will remain supported.