# Matplotlib ignores date information when plotting timstamp

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot a line chart with timestamp and values, but even thought my timestamp column in is datetime format, when I plot it, it won't show the date information like yyyy-mm-dd, but only the time.

[image]

The code I used to plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot('timestamp', 'values', data=df, marker='', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=1, color='skyblue', linewidth=1)
```

The axis looks like below with no date information.

[image]

Comment: You didn't tell matplotlib which format you would like to have, so it uses the seamingly most useful one for intraday data.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, how do I let matplotlib know which format I want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968985/changing-the-formatting-of-a-datetime-axis-in-matplotlib