# axis ticks dateformatter is not working correctly on line chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, date-formatting

I am able to render a line chart by using my plotting data but x-axis tickers is not showing correctly. Because my dataframe has `period` `datetimeindex` object and I want to show them along x axis correctly. I tried several existing posts about `axis ticker` but still I didn't have a correct plot. How to fix this? any idea? thanks

**EDA data**

here is the [plotting data on gist](https://gist.github.com/forzaPhd/28100d43745942383e65b06a0893849a)

**my attempt**:

here is my current attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv('plot_data.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df.div(df.Total, axis=0).applymap(lambda x: f'{x * 100:.2f}%')
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,6))
_ = df.div(df.Total, axis=0).iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='line', ax=ax1, ax=ax1, marker='o',ls='--')
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.0%}'.format(y))) 
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d-%Y'))
plt.show()
```

**goal**

I want to render a line chart where the y-axis should show percentage while the x-axis should show periods along the years correctly. In my code, x-axis tickers are not showing correctly. Any idea?

Comment: Just curious why you want to show each day when your data is by quarter? It looks pretty good if it's just showing the years as the x-axis tick labels.

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik not day but periods such as `2014-01-01, 2014-04-01` and so on. I am trying to show by quarter. any idea? why ticking is not working here?

Comment: I can't make heads nor tails of what's going on with the DateFormatter. Maybe KT12 is on to something about there being a pandas issue with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to let pandas do its thing.  To have dates in the x-axis, pandas likes to have these dates as index. Just do `df.set_index('quarter', inplace=True)`.

With such an index, pandas will set an x-axis that looks like a date, but in reality is a categorical axis (numbered 0,1,2,3,...) where pandas provides the ticklabels.

To set the percentages, use the `PercentFormatter`, with parameters to set the 100% (to 1, not to the default 100) and the number of decimals.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

filename = 'plot_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')
df.set_index('quarter', inplace=True)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 6))
df.div(df.Total, axis=0).iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='line', ax=ax1, marker='o', ls='--')
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(xmax=1, decimals=0))
plt.xticks(range(len(df.index)), df.index, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Alternatively, you could convert the index to matplotlib dates and use matplotlib's formatting and locators:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

filename = 'plot_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')
df.quarter = [pd.to_datetime(d).date() for d in df.quarter]
df.set_index('quarter', inplace=True)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 6))
_ = df.div(df.Total, axis=0).iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='line', ax=ax1, marker='o', ls='--')
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(xmax=1, decimals=0))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=1, interval=3))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d-%Y'))
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot using matplotlib dates]

Comment: this plot is confusing because understanding the x-axis is not so easy. is that possible to make a plot like this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968985/changing-the-formatting-of-a-datetime-axis-in-matplotlib)? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The `quarter` column was converted to `datetime` format and then set as the index:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv('plot_data.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df['quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df['quarter'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index(df['quarter'])
df = df.sort_index()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,6))
_ = df.drop('quarter', axis=1).div(df.Total, axis=0).iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='line', ax=ax1)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.0%}'.format(y))) 
ax1.set_xticks(df.index)
ax1.xaxis_date()
plt.show()
```

[image]

After struggling with matplotlib, I found a solution using seaborn.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
df = pd.read_csv('plot_data.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df['quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df['quarter'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index(df['quarter'])
df = df.sort_index()
df_clean = df.drop('quarter', axis=1).div(df.Total, axis=0)
df_clean.drop('Total', axis=1, inplace=True)
df_us = df_clean.unstack().reset_index().copy()
df_us = df_us.rename(columns={'level_0':'Country', 0:'Percent'})
g = sns.lineplot(data=df_us, x='quarter', y='Percent', hue='Country')
g.set(xticks=df.index)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
g.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.0%}'.format(y)))
plt.savefig('sns.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Edited the code and was able to chart the dates on the x-axis.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure why the `DateFormatter` is changing the date to something completely different.

Comment: Might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26253)

Comment: @beyond_inifinity : KT12 spent quite some effort and time trying to help you