# pyplot does not have attribute 'xaxis_set_major_formatter'

Tags: python, datetime, xticks

I am trying to plot hours in the x-axis [in this picture] using this code

```
#create a lineplot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
plt.title('SUBIC-NAIA Air Temp Difference. (C)')
ax.plot(date_rng,NASU_dif)
monthyearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d-%h')
plt.xaxis_set_major_formatter(monthyearFmt)
plt.xlabel('Time Step (hr)')
plt.ylabel('Air Temperature (m/s)')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', prop={'size': 10})
plt.show()
```

but I am receiving

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute
>   'xaxis_set_major_formatter'

I have a daterng as my index. How do I solve this one?

> DatetimeIndex(['2018-04-22 00:00:00', '2018-04-22 01:00:00',
>                  '2018-04-22 02:00:00', '2018-04-22 03:00:00',
>                  '2018-04-22 04:00:00', '2018-04-22 05:00:00',
>                  '2018-04-22 06:00:00', '2018-04-22 07:00:00',
>                  '2018-04-22 08:00:00', '2018-04-22 09:00:00',
>                  ...
>                  '2018-04-29 15:00:00', '2018-04-29 16:00:00',
>                  '2018-04-29 17:00:00', '2018-04-29 18:00:00',
>                  '2018-04-29 19:00:00', '2018-04-29 20:00:00',
>                  '2018-04-29 21:00:00', '2018-04-29 22:00:00',
>                  '2018-04-29 23:00:00', '2018-04-30 00:00:00'],
>                 dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=193, freq='H')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the formatting of a datetime axis in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968985/changing-the-formatting-of-a-datetime-axis-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 3):

Find the [`set_major_formatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter.html) method on the `Axis` object (e.g. `ax.xaxis`).

```py
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d-%h'))
```

If you don't use subplots, you can access the axis object via the [`gca()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html) method (get current axis)

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    
plt.plot(... 

ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d-%h'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `xaxis.set_major_formatter`

Also, `xaxis` is property of `ax`. So you could do

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthyearFmt)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I did not notice the '_' part. Although, even after using xaxis.set_major_formatter, I get module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'xaxis'

Comment: @kaelel18 mind the `ax`. `xaxis` is a property of axes not `pyplot`.