# pd.to_datetime US to Europe datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change my axis x where the value are 2019-01, 2019-02..
To 01-01-2019, 01-02-2019...
I find it's due to the pd.to_datetime US default.
I try different thing but nothing change...

```
ax1.plot(pd.to_datetime(DB['Date'], dayfirst=True), θPf2plot, color = 'gray', label = "Capacité au champ") 
ax1.plot(pd.to_datetime(DB['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y'), θPf2plot, color = 'gray', label = "Capacité au champ")
```

If you have any ideas, thank you for your help :) !

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data and expected output? Its not very clear what needs to be done

Answer (score 1):

pd.to_datetime just converts a string to datetimes. But it does not change the format.

To change the format in matplotlib you have to use DateFormatter as explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968985/changing-the-formatting-of-a-datetime-axis-in-matplotlib).

It is hard to tell from your code snippet, but the solution should look like this:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax1.set_xticks(pd.to_datetime(DB['Date'])
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%d/%m/%Y"))
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks!